# Change style of a child component using parent class from parent component's style file

Tags: html, reactjs, sass, jsx, css-modules

I have `TrackCard` component defined as:

```
<React.Fragment>
  {this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
    <div className={classes['genre-col']} key={index}> //<--------
      <div className={classes['track-single']}>
        <div className={classes['track-img-container']}>
          <img src={item.url} alt="" className={classes['track-image']} />
        </div>
        <div className={classes.genre}>
          <h6>{item.name}</h6>
          <p>{item.artist}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ))}
</React.Fragment>
```

The `genre-col` class is defined in `Music.scss`

```
.genre-col {
    width: 20%;
}
```

Now I am accessing the `TrackCard` Component in another Component named `Feeds` as follows  and the styles are defined in `Feeds.scss` :

```
<div className={`${classes['feed-cover']}`}>
    <TrackCard  items={this.state.tracks}/>
</div>
```

But here I need to change the width of the `.genre-col` without affecting other components. So I need to access `.genre-col` using the parent class in `Feeds` Component and define it in `Feeds.scss`.

I tried to import the style files in both the components and define the class globally. But there was no result.
I use SCSS modules for styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct Me if I'm wrong. As I understood, What you want is to control TrackCard from Feeds Component. There are few ways to do that. 
 1. Create a class in Feeds.css and pass it to TrackCard like below

```
<TrackCard  items={this.state.tracks} customClass={classes['track-card']}/>
```

and Inside TrackCard

```
{this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
     <div className={classnames(classes['genre-col'], this.props.customClass)} key={index}> />
```

`classnames` is a library for the doing class concatenation and stuff easily. Have a look at the [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames).

2.Define different classes which represents various sizes, you want, inside Music.scss itself. Pass a prop from Feeds like in below code.

```
.small { width: 300px; }
.medium { width: 500px; }
.large { width: 800px; }
```

For TrackCard pass needed size as props.

```
<TrackCard  items={this.state.tracks} size={'medium'}/>
```

and Inside TrackCard

```
{this.props.items.map((item, index) => (
     <div className={classnames(classes['genre-col'], classes[this.props.size])} key={index}> />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the first method :)